# Size UIContainerView based on embedded UI elements?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, uicontainerview

**I am developing a simple app in iOS using Swift as the language...**

I have the UI set out for a screen below as shown in the diagram:

[image: Screen layout diagram]

The Container View height needs to be set on the number of lines of text in a UILabel inside the view.

**How can I set the height of the Container View based on the content within the Container View?**

Comment: If you want cell height to be dynamic based on it's label's text then use it self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400 //Just give a maximum value
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension // This will take automatically.

Comment: @Max, just after creating & populating the cell of your table view, get the height of the cell and reframe the container view by setting the height of the container view as cell's height

Comment: Sorry @SanjayMohnani how do I check and set those heights? (I'm still trying to wrap my head around everything Swift :)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand but I think this is what you want self.tableView.rowHeight

Comment: If there only ever be 1 cell, why is your Container View `UItableView` instead of simple `UIView`?

Comment: Good point Jakub...the reason I was using a cell is because I know how to resize height of cells automatically based on the lines of text given to a UILabel in the cell. How would I program the UIView to resize to fit the number of lines of a UILabel that I want to show in it?